# CSS: Directory page with one <ul> that has a fixed number of lines

Tags: html, css, html-lists

Sorry for the unclear phrasing in the title. I'll briefly explain what I mean.

I am trying to generate a directory page (A-Z) that is basically one big < ul>. However, I want it to "fold" after 25 < li>, creating let's say 4 columns of 25 < li>, and then below again 4 columns, and so on and on.

I want this to automatically happen given that I have a few hundred entries and I do not want to manually put them in 4 columns of 25 < li>. If I add one < li> in the middle, it should push all the other entries down (not getting one list of 26).

e.g.with colums of 5

[image]

Adding one, pushes all < li> afterward further.

[image]

I hope this kind off illustrates what I am trying to do. Pretty sure I can write a script to do this as well but I wonder if there is a better way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

CSS Grid can do most of that:

```css
  ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-grid;
  /* or grid depending on your need */
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, auto);
  background: lightblue;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  padding: .25em;
  border: 1px solid grey;
   }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
  <li>Item 6</li>
  <li>Item 7</li>
  <li>Item 8</li>
  <li>Item 9</li>
  <li>Item 10</li>
  <li>Item 11</li>
  <li>Item 12</li>
  <li>Item 13</li>
  <li>Item 14</li>
  <li>Item 15</li>
  <li>Item 16</li>
  <li>Item 17</li>
  <li>Item 18</li>
  <li>Item 19</li>
  <li>Item 20</li>
  <li>Item 21</li>
  <li>Item 22</li>

</ul>
```

**However**, I do not think there is a CSS property that will allow the list to "wrap/fold" to a second set of vertical rows.

Comment: Hi @Paulie_D, thanks for your reply. This nearly accomplishes it. The only problem is that it continues to extend rightward, out of the page. I want it to work exactly like this, but instead of continuing off page, I want it to fold and start a new row of columns below. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: As I said, I'm 99% sure this is not possible with just CSS. Unfortunately, I think you JS solution is the only option or break the output into separate sections (or `ul`) and apply the CSS above to each one.